# Angular 5: How to get a checkbox to be checked on an edit component from an array that has a checked=true attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array that I am retrieving from a data object from the API service call. I am attaching a checked attribute to that array so that the checkboxes will be selected in the component ngOnInit().

I have a master checkbox list but only want the ones coming back from the service call to be selected.

I have tried using a bunch of methods, including for loops and .forEach() on the array.

```
  this.filterService.GetTierContent(this.config.id, "MCC").subscribe(data 
     => {
  data.forEach(i => this.selectedMcc.push({ type: "MCC", data: i.data, 
  checked: true }));    
  });

for(var i=0; i < this.selectedMcc.length; i++){
var index = this.selectedMcc.findIndex(i => i.data == i);
  if(this.selectedMcc[index].checked === true) {
    this.chk1 = true;
  }    
  else {
    this.chk1 = false;
  }
}  


  <div *ngFor="let a of apparel; let i = index"> 
            <mat-checkbox value="{{a.id}}" [(ngModel)] ="chk1" 
   (change)="onChecked(a, $event)">
                {{a.mccCode}}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
```

Expected result:

`[(ngModel)]` will hold a `true` or `false` value based on what the loop provides. Only the data array coming back from the service should be checked on component load (by default).

Actual results as of now: checking one box, checks all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what about this approach?:

```
// First of all, we set all checked-states to false in the apparel-list
this.apparel.forEach(element => {
    element.checked = false;
});

// then we loop through the new list
this.selectedMcc.forEach( element => {
    // if an element is checked, check its counterpart in the apparel-list
    if (el.checked === true) {
        this.apparel.filter(item => item.id === element.id)[0].checked = true;
    }
});

// as result you should now have only those items from the incoming list selected
<div *ngFor="let a of apparel; let i = index"> 
    <mat-checkbox 
        value="{{a.id}}" 
        [(ngModel)]="a.checked" // bind the checked-value of the item in the apparel-list
        (change)="onChecked(a, $event)">
        {{a.mccCode}}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

PS: it supposes that elements in the apparel-list have a `checked`-field too.

Comment: The only problem is that data does not bring back an id so I cannot filter by id, only the mccCode (data) itself...I'm trying this but doesn't seem to work:
`if (element.checked === true) {
      this.apparel.filter(item => item.mccCode === element.mccCode)[0].checked = true;
      
  }`

Comment: I mean data does not bring back the same id, once it gets saved to the database, it changes...so your example won't work. Need to compare the actual strings.